# Yaml dump in Python

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I've the following document:

```
stack = """
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: My description
Resources: {{}}
"""
```

which I try to dump in an yaml file but without any luck:

```
import yaml
import os

d='access'
stack = """
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: My Description
Resources: {{}}
"""

doc = yaml.load(stack)

stack_path = os.path.join('.', '{}-stack.yaml'.format(d))
with open(stack_path, 'w+b') as stack_file:
    stack_file.write(yaml.dump(
        doc,
        default_flow_style=False,
        encoding='utf-8'
    ))
```

I get this result back:

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 33:
            AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
```

do you have any idea?

Comment: Appears to be running fine when I try it on Py 3.6. What python version are you using?

Comment: ... works on 2.7.13 as well.

Comment: yes you are right. the point is that this is just a part of the code. I'm trying to reproduce the error with the smallest quantity of code and then I'll repost it again

Comment: Updated now with the example that raise the issue

Comment: I'm running in MacOS with Atom

Comment: Did you try to minimize the example by removing the last two lines. The only thing that looks funny to me is the `{{}}` value (i.e. a mapping as key without a value within a mapping).

Comment: If I remove the last two lines i don't get that error. that `{{}}` is there ofc because I need to have in my document the string `{}` so I need to escape it

Comment: Yes, the curly braces are the culprit here. You might want to replace it with something and then change it back in the yaml later?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're bothering with yaml load and dump at all. You have a string, you want to write a string; why not just write the contents of `stack` directly to the file?

Comment: I want to read `stack` and then append to `Resources` other YAML files that I read through Python

Comment: Well where is the code that is doing that? Because you can't with the code you have shown.

Comment: I don't think is important for this issue. It's outside of the scope. The error is raised for other reasons

Comment: But it is. I say you don't need to bother with loading or re-serializing the yaml because you could just write the string. You claim you do need to, but don't show any code that backs that up.

Comment: Not to mention, even if you do need this for some reason it's not clear why you think you need to "escape" the brackets. `Resources: {}` works fine.

Comment: Ok but the point is not that bracket. the point is to read YAML file and then append to `Resources` dict. If I don't load the YAML then I can't append easily other YAML files to it

Comment: ok found the issue finally. I removed the top `---` typical yaml lines and now it works

Comment: @Mazzy You cannot escape `{` by doubling them in YAML. If you want to have the string `{}` you should quote (double, or single) to make sure you get a string: `"{}"`

Comment: Actually by doubling them it works

Comment: Only because something is wrong in the parser. Try the minimal `python -c 'import yaml; yaml.safe_load("a: {{}}")'` and you'll see the error. BTW you should never use `yaml.load()`, it is documented that that is unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the top `---` YAML lines now it works

Comment: The `---` is not at the top, it is on the second line, because you have a newline after the initial `"""`. If you don't want that newline then use `stack = """\ `